# CMake: ''Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid" ; OpenPose

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-18.04, openpose

I'm trying to build OpenPose from the source code, but however I get this error message. Please help me.

Here is the log from CMake-GUI:

```
Building with CUDA.
CUDA detected: 9.1
Added CUDA NVCC flags for: sm_61
cuDNN not found
Could NOT find GFlags (missing: GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR GFLAGS_LIBRARY) 
Could NOT find Glog (missing: GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR GLOG_LIBRARY) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:543 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:431 (find_package)
```

Here are the last few lines from CMakeErrorLog

```
Linking C executable cmTC_54d83
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_54d83.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc -fPIC -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_54d83.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o $
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_54d83.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_54d83' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_54d83] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/idl/PycharmProjects/openpose/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_54d83/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_54d83/fast] Error 2
```

I have installed the required dependencies- CUDA, CuDNN, CAFFE, CV2...

Comment: ''Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid" - It is just an indicator about some error occured on the configuration stage. The **actual error** you have is "Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)". As you can guess, this error is about not finding Protobuf. Do you have Protobuf installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I’ve made sure to install Protobuf.

Comment: Where do you install it? Where are `google/protobuf/service.h` or other header files are located? (If you have protobuf installed via package manager, then it should be `protobuf-dev` package to be installed).